# Relational Algebra First and Last Date

Tags: relational-algebra

I just started learning Database Relational Algebra, and I got stuck on these 2 questions.

The original question was more complicated but I managed to narrow it down and simplify to the tables below, I couldn't figure out how to do it, help plz.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting, as order is not a concept normally present in relational algebra. We therefore have use a workaround. We're going to use two copies of the relation `R`, I'll call one `X`, and the other `Y`:

1. Equi-join `X` and `Y` on the name attribute, which gives us the relation attributes `(X.id, X.date, X.name, Y.id, Y.date, Y.name)`. I'll call this joined relation `J`.
2. Select from the `J` entries that satisfy `X.date < Y.date`. We now have a relation where the first date for a donor exists only in `X.date` and the last date exists only in `Y.date`.
3. We take the original relation `R` and project `(R.date, R.name)` to get all dates a donor donated on.
4. Finally, to obtain a relation of first dates, we project `(Y.date, Y.name)` (which doesn't have first dates), and do the set difference `First dates = (R.date, R.name)\(Y.date, Y.name)`. Similarly, `Last dates = (R.date, R.name)\(X.date, X.name)`.